# How to make the user able to filter on certain field in a model (Django)

Tags: django

Say I have a model of cars

```py
#models.py
class Car(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeingKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   n_doors = models.IntegerField(default=5)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

and a user has created 6 `Car`, where 3 have 5 doors, 2 have 4 doors and 1 have 1 door.

Is there a way I can let the user filter on, say, `n_doors` either by a choice-list of available numbers ([5,4,1]), or by letting the user write numbers theirself?

Answer (score 0):

Try [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html), it shall be useful to solve your problem.

Comment: Consider adding an example and some explanation to the answer. For instance here OP needs to use [`AllValuesFilter` (django-filter docs)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#allvaluesfilter) whose choices are the current values in the database.